# How do I check for a keyword in a MessageEmbed?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, embed

I have a function that looks for a keyword inside all the text of the embeds of a message: I know it's a long way to do that, but I wouldn't know how to accomplish the same thing otherwise.

I got this function from another post on this topic, but I get this error, and if I can't. Is there another way to get the data from an embed?

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const config = require("./config.json")

function findInMessage(message, target, {
  caseSensitive = false,
  author = false,
  description = true,
  footer = true,
  title = true,
  fields = true
}) {
  if (!target || !message) return null;
  let str = caseSensitive ? target : target.toLowerCase();

  if ((caseSensitive && message.content.includes(str)) ||
    (!caseSensitive && message.content.toLowerCase().includes(str))) return true;

  for (let embed of message.embeds) {
    if ((caseSensitive && (
        (author && embed.author.includes(str)) ||
        (description && embed.description.includes(str)) ||
        (footer && embed.footer.includes(str)) ||
        (title && embed.title.includes(str)))) ||
      (!caseSensitive && (
        (author && embed.author.toLowerCase().includes(str)) ||
        (description && embed.description.toLowerCase().includes(str)) ||
        (footer && embed.footer.toLowerCase().includes(str)) ||
        (title && embed.title.toLowerCase().includes(str))))
    ) return true;

    if (fields)
      for (let field of embed.fields) {
        if ((caseSensitive && [field.name, field.value].includes(str)) ||
          (!caseSensitive && [field.name.toLowerCase(), field.value.toLowerCase()].includes(str))) return true;
      }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Error:

```
     caseSensitive = false,
    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'caseSensitive' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

The function itself seems to be ok for checking the embeds: the only problem is that it's using object destructuring with an optional parameter which has no default value. This should be easily fixable by just setting the options to a default `{}` value, so that if you don't enter it will use the default option.
This is how you can do it:

```js
function findInMessage(message, target, {
    caseSensitive = false,
    author = false,
    description = true,
    footer = true,
    title = true,
    fields = true
} = {}) { // The change is here, in the '= {}'
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed that problem, but now I'm getting

`TypeError: embed.footer.includes is not a function`

I am on discord.js@11.4.2

Any way to fix this?